Converting elastic search CURL request into java
I have the below functioning curl request
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/search_request/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "logRequestId"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'


Now, I want to get the java code to do this.
I know there are various methods e.g. SearchSourceBuilder in Rest High Level client to do so. But my elastic client is Low level. Following is the code where I establist connection to the ES client
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(elasticsearchHostname, elasticsearchPort)).build();
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
        this.esClient = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

Is there any way to achieve the objective possibly in a production ready code?

It should be something like this:
SearchResponse<Void> response = esClient.search(sr -> sr
    .index("search_request")
    .query(q -> q.exists(eq -> eq.field("logRequestId")))
, Void.class);

I added it as a test in my demo project.
I also recommend reading this blog post.

Thanks! This worked for me. That blog post was also really helpful.
